# Drawing just within the inside of an SVG or JPEG/PNG

Tags: c#, .net, canvas, svg, drawing

I am trying to make a Program where you can draw on either a SVG or a JPG/PNG. BUT, this drawing is limited to only the INSIDES of the outline. For a better visualisation, look at this Picture - http://www.clker.com/cliparts/c/9/8/9/1237099922676360396kelan_Human_figure.svg

So, right here we see a human shape, outlined with a black line.
What I need is basically that you can draw inside of the humans body and its head, but everything outside of the shape should not be able to be colored.

I have tried using SharpVector (A Nuget-Package) as well as the standart-Canvas so far but I have not been successive so far. Also I cannot provide any Codesamples since they help nothing anyway, at least I think so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: My original answer was:

> Yes this can be done with SVG graphics. You need to extract the path
>   from the file and calculate `Points` and graphic items that scale to
>   your drawing canvas.

Now, this was naive. Looking closer at the SVG format I have to say that even with simple images this is not going to be easy, in fact it is a rather tall order..

The rest is correct:

> ..Then you can convert them to a `Region` and use it to clip the
>   `Graphics` object you will use to do your drawing.
>
> See an example about clipping regions [here on
>   MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/155t36zz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
>
> As for a JPEG image this is not so simple. I'm not sure how I'd do it;
>   at the moment I'm thinking about floodfilling the outside and XORing
>   the result with the canvas but that sounds terribly expensive..

Now, where does this leave you? Well I guess you need to get that outline path I thought the SVG data would supply.

Here is a solution that you may find too tedious or perfectly ok: You have to trace the outline and use the trace results to create the clipping region. The tracing is a manual task, but for the example file it can be done with reasonable precision in about a minute.

Here are a few routines to set up a minimal tracing program. You need a pictureBox to display the image as jpg, png or whatever; svg is not directly supported in .NET. Set the PB to zoom and anchor it on all sides. Add a few buttons and you can start..

```
// We collect the trace data in a list:
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

// each mouse click adds a point
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{  points.Add(e.Location);   pictureBox1.Invalidate();   }

// show all all trace points
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{   if (points.Count < 2) return;
    e.Graphics.DrawCurve(Pens.OrangeRed, points.ToArray());
    foreach (Point p in points) 
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, p.X - 1, p.Y - 1, 3, 3);
}

// always good to have an undo button
private void cb_Undo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ if (points.Count > 0) { points.RemoveAt(points.Count-1); pictureBox1.Invalidate();} }

// start a new trace by initializing the list
private void cb_NewTrace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ points = new List<Point>();  pictureBox1.Invalidate();  }
```

Now that we can collect the trace points we'll need a way to save and load them. Many ways to do that, esp. Serialization comes to mind. But these simple functions are hard to beat in terms of shortness:

```
void savePoints(List<Point> points, string filename)
{   StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Point P in points) SB.AppendLine(P.X.ToString() + ";" + P.Y.ToString());
    File.WriteAllText(filename, SB.ToString());
}

List<Point> loadPoints(string filename)
{   List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
    foreach (string l in lines)
    {
        var p = l.Split(';');
        points.Add(new Point(Convert.ToInt16(p[0]), Convert.ToInt16(p[1])));
    }
    return points;
}
```

With Buttons to Load an Image, start a Trace, Undo a click, save and load the trace data all we need is one button to test the whole thing:

```
// non-persistent test routine that will draw randomly in the picturebox
private void cb_Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics G = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics())
    {
        // set up the graphicsPath
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.AddCurve(points.ToArray());
        // create the clipping region
        Region region = new Region(path);
        G.SetClip(region, CombineMode.Replace);
        // now we're good to go..
        // note: all drawing is done on the full range of the box!
        G.FillRectangle(Brushes.GhostWhite, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
        Random R = new Random();
        int xMax = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width;
        int yMax = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            int x1 = R.Next(xMax);  int y1 = R.Next(yMax);
            int x2 = R.Next(xMax);  int y2 = R.Next(yMax);
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(
                        255, x1 & 255, y1 & 255, x2 * y2 & 255), 10f))
                G.DrawLine(pen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a preview of such a trace, consisting of only 94 points and a test fill of it:

[image: trace points][image: filled trace]

Comment: But, that thing with the Points, Region and Graphics should work you say?

Comment: Well, maybe it is not so very simple. Looking at the example it seems that way, but the full SVG format does have quite a few hurdles.. So maybe looking for a libary is a good idea. But it will work, just like the example, that does just that, just with fewer points..

Comment: Hmrh... You can not, by chance, make an example? I an straddling with this right now and have barely an Idea how to do that.

Comment: So I now have tried something different ant it PARTIALLY works now. Is it possible to look at it?

Comment: I'll look at it. Where is it?

Comment: Okay, I got it to work so far. Also, now for nearly an hour I was trying to be able to draw with my mouse but I did not manage that yet. Is it possible that you can send me a snippet on how i am possible to draw on the inside of the points with my mouse and NOT able to draw out of the points?

Comment: Using my code or what?

Comment: I got to work it with integrating your code into mine so far. I should have said I wanted to do it in WPF, but it works in WinForms too. That was the problem - Without WindowsFormsHosts you cannot use PictureBox. Anyway - how to do the Mouse-Drawing now? I am trying the whole time but all I manage is that i draw on the whole boy and not only inside of the points of the List.

Comment: We have a problem here - I can't really help without knoing more about your code or about your level of programming Winforms. For the latter the golden rule is to either draw only in or from the Paint event or to draw into a bitmap. Which do you do? The 3rd option is to draw onto the Control without being connected to the Paint event. This is a mistake!

Comment: When you want to restrict drawing to the imside you nedd 1) the trace points; do you have some? and b) you must set the clipping for the Graphics you use to draw. Look at the test code! It makes the mistake of drawing outside the paint event but you can see ho it sets up the clipping region. It is only a test and therefore it is ok that the drawing doesn'r pesist, say mimizing the form. Your drawing must survive these events! The way to go is to create a draw action class and to fill a list of that class with all the data for each action, incl. position & pen..

Comment: Note, that __creating__ a set of trace points and __using__ to clip drawing it, are either jobs for two different programs or two modes of the same program! - Do you know the basics of drawing with a mouse?

Comment: I am not too experienced on drawing with a mouse, and that is the reason why I search here for help. But that does not mean I did not try it before, I spent a lot of time looking up the things in the MSDN-Library and got to work everything except drawing with the mouse inside of the point-List (The Figure) and avoid to draw out of the lines

Comment: ok, please read my comments again let them sink in and try to answer __each__ question, ok?

Comment: To draw either into or from the Paint event or into a bitmap - I basically need to get the whole picture (With the body and the color I drew) to save as a Picture-File - How it is done does not matter.     Trace-Points - I do have them saved into a Textfile with your code, so yeah, I have them I guess?      And the basics of drawing with a mouse - I answered that just before

Comment: That were all the Questions you had asked, right?

Comment: Well, almost. I still don't know which way you draw. But I guess it will be best, if you have a look at a very simple demo I wrote: I reads the points file and lets you draw on a clipped canvas; also lets you save the drawing. Very simple. No frills no error checking no color picker or width changer, just the bare bones to prove the clipping works.. Look for it [here](http://www.file-upload.net/download-9522836/ClipDraw.zip.html)

Comment: You forgot to include the Solutionfile, but thank you. I will take a look at it

Comment: So, I tried out the Program - And it does not work for me or I am too stupid. I start the Program (After referencing to my Points-File I created) and yet I only see a white picturebox with a red, crossed line in it. I cannot draw or load a picture into it or whatever.

Comment: That's strange. I have uploaded the [full solution](http://www.file-upload.net/download-9522924/ClipDraw.zip.html) now, including my own points file. You can also try the exe in the bin folder..

Comment: Just one more thing! I have included a Colorchanger now and when I draw in yellow, then click a button to draw in red, and then draw on the Picture again it changes the already done strokes also to red. How can I avoid that? I assumed that e.Graphics.DrawLine() does put a line like I draw with the mouse and doesnt change the already drawn?

Comment: Look at the `actions.Add(new drawAction(lastMousePos, e.Location, col, width) );` call in the mousemove! here each line gets its color stored.. and in the Paint (and the save) it is used: `using (Pen pen = new Pen(DA.c, DA.w))`  There is a class variable `col`; yopu should set it like so: `if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) col = colorDialog1.Color;`

Comment: Well, I looked at it but it doesnt help me with the fact that the LineWidth and LineColor of everythign I draw changes when I change it for the next line I want to draw... Hmh...

Comment: You must change the class variables; don't change anything in the Paint event!

Comment: Thank you very much, and I would love it to talk to you sometime again! You are the best!

Comment: Thanks.- A final note: The ClipDraw is really just a __very quick and very dirty hack__ to demostrate the Clipping. For a Paint program the first thing, after understanding what ClipDraw __does__ and how,  is to realize what it __doesn't__ and  what you want to add. The drawAction class should have an action __type__ for lines, curves etc; an action should have a `List<Point>` to hold all points that are drawn with the same pen and in one stroke so they can be drawn with one `DrawLines` or `DrawCurves` instead of many `DrawLine` or `DrawCurve` commands, which tend to leave gaps etc.. Have fun!

Comment: Also, I just figured out - What if I want to have lets say, a Dog and a Human? Right now the Program can only do a single figure which doesnt let me make points for separate figures. How should this be handled?

Comment: This can be done. `Region` supports `set` operations. With one region for each of 2 figures you can do : R3 = R2.Clone();  R3.Union(R1); now R3 will consist of two spearate areas you can use for clipping..  You would create them separately, then read in those you want to combine and do the Union thing for as many as you need; you'll have to take care of the positions, i.e. you may want to translate them to the right or so.. They also may overlap, but tha't not what you want, usually. You see: doable but it'll take some more though and time..

Comment: And it would probably be a good idea to expand the creation of the trace point list to include a move command that indicates a break in the figure and a move to the start of a new figure. Ha! Just where I was when I read the SVG specs.. If I do that I'll keep you posted ;-)